# How can I link multiple webassembly modules? I am using reference interpreter to compile S-exp to wasm?

Tags: webassembly

Importer module:

```
(module
    (type $GG (func (param i32) (result i32)))

       (import "low" "load" (func $load (param i32) (result i32)))
       (table (import "low" "table") 2 anyfunc)
       (func (export "func_0") (result i32) 
        (call_indirect $GG (i32.const 0) (i32.const 0))  
       )
)
```

Exporter module:

```
(module
  (table 2 anyfunc)
  (memory $0 100)
  (export "memory" (memory $0))
  (export "load" (func $local))
  (func $local (param $0 i32) (result i32)
    (i32.load (get_local $0))
  )
)
```

I am trying to compile following two modules to `wasm` and then load using JS API. I am trying to use following JS code to make the import work:

```
var h = fetch("test.wasm")
.then(function(response) {
    return response.arrayBuffer();
})
var l = fetch("low.wasm").
then(function(response){
        return response.arrayBuffer();
    })

var exp  = l.then( function(buffer){ 
    var moduleBufferView = new Uint8Array(buffer);  
    WebAssembly.instantiate(moduleBufferView)  
        .then(function(instantiated) {
            const instance = instantiated.instance;
            return instance.exports
        })
})

fetch("test.wasm")
.then(function(response) {
    return response.arrayBuffer();
})
.then(function(buffer) {
    var moduleBufferView = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    WebAssembly.instantiate(moduleBufferView, exp)
        .then(function(instantiated) {
            const instance = instantiated.instance;
            document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = instance.exports.func_0();


        })
});
```

While compiling using reference interpreter I am getting following error:
`test.wast:4.8-4.67: link failure: unknown import "low"."load"`.

Error does make sense that test module is unaware of low while compiling, but how can I link them together?

Answer (score 2):

By default, the reference interpreter *interprets* (i.e., executes and instantiates) the module definitions in its input script. If you want to use it to [convert](https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/tree/master/interpreter#converting-modules-or-scripts) files between formats then you have to invoke like e.g.

```
wasm -d module.wat -o module.wasm
```

See the [section on converting files](https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/tree/master/interpreter#converting-modules-or-scripts) in the [README](https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/tree/master/interpreter) of the interpreter.

Btw, the table in your program is never initialised, so the `call_indirect` will just trap. Your JavaScript glue also looks a bit strange: for example, `instance.exports.()` is not valid JavaScript, and why are you trying to assign it to a DOM node?

Comment: `instance.exports.()` is a typo. It should have beeen `instance.exports.func_0` and high module should export `func_0`. I have corrected it.

Comment: You're now exporting it twice. ;).